# In net code for a C# game, I'm seeing an issue where the system is returning negatives. Can anyone spot why or offer improvements?

Tags: c#, server, multiplayer

The main "Ping"/"Time" function for the game is this:

[Net Code For Server - Time/Ping](http://pastebin.com/s3rTYbN9)

Outside of the switch, TimeSync() functions like this:

```
private void TimeSync()
{
    YGConnection.Send("Time", DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);
}
```

It sends the current UTCNow.Millisecond time to the server.

Finally, getTime() gets the current time + the offset of the server.

```
private double getTime()
{
    return Math.Round((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds) + Offset;
}
```

It all works, but the numbers produced are like this:

Version 0.1.5 : Server time offset: -486335789940 - Ping: -943491433067

The server basically sends getTime() back, but without the offset. I'm wondering what is going on with the negative numbers and if there is anything I can do to fix that.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up units, that offset is not measured in milliseconds.

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond` is value of milliseconds in timestamp (i.e. a number in range [0, 999]). Are you sure this is the number you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DateTime.Milliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) within the current second.  If you only compare Milliseconds, you will lose any information like the second it occurred in.

At midnight it is 00:00:00.000

500 milliseconds later it is 00:00:00.500

500 milliseconds later it is 00:00:01.000

If you are just comparing the milliseconds, the difference between the first two times will be 500.
The difference between the last two will be -500.

What you probably want to do is return a whole date/time value rather than just the milliseconds.  If you subtract 2 DateTime objects, you get a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) object.  From that you can find the [TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will give you how many milliseconds there are between those two times regardless of how many seconds have elapsed.

Comment: That did it, with a little work I've redone my lag/latency and transmitted DateTime directly instead of trying to convert to numerics.  System is now responding in much smaller numbers and positive.

Comment: Version 0.1.5 : Server time offset: 1474057869632 - Ping: 788.1565